# Normal Bundle to flag manifold/variety

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannian

Let $Fl(k_1,k_2) = \{ (V_1,V_2)\in G_{k_1}(V)\times G_{k_2}(V):\text{ }V_1\subset V_2\}$ be a two step flag manifold over a $n$ - dimensional vector space $V$. I am mostly interested in the case $V =\mathbb{C}^n$. I want to construct a normal bundle to $Fl(k_1,k_2)$ in the product $G_{k_1}(V)\times G_{k_2}(V)$ using tautological bundles and I think it should be very well studied although I could not find what I was looking for in the literature.

My own construction goes as follows: Let $\gamma^{k_1}(V)$ and $\gamma^{k_2}(V)$ be the tautological bundles over $G_{k_1}(V)$ and $G_{k_2}(V)$ and fix $(V_1,V_2)\in G_{k_1}(V)\times G_{k_2}(V)$. Then there is a natural bilinear pairing $$ V_1\times (V_2)^\circ\rightarrow \mathbb{K},\quad (v,\phi)\mapsto \phi(v),$$ inducing a linear map $$s(V_1,V_2): V_1\otimes (V_2)^\circ\rightarrow\mathbb{K}.$$ By construction $s(V_1,V_2)$ is the zero map if and only if $V_1\subset V_2$. Let $\pi_i : G_{k_1}(V)\times G_{k_2}(V) \rightarrow G_{k_i}(V)$, $i=1,2$ be natural projections. Then $s$ should define a section of the bundle $$\mu := \text{Hom}(\pi_1^*(\gamma^{k_1}(V))\otimes \pi_2^*(\gamma^{k_2}(V)^\circ),\mathbb{K}) \cong \pi_1^*(\gamma^{k_1}(V))^*\otimes \pi_2^*(\gamma^{k_2}(V)^\circ)^*,$$
where $\gamma^{k_2}(V)^\circ$ is the "annihilator bundle" of $\gamma^{k_2}(V)$ (a term I could not find in the literature, but the total space conists of pairs $(W,\phi)$ with $W \in G_{k_2}(V)$ and $\phi\in W^\circ$, so I guess this should be a vector bundle of rank $(n-k_2)$ by some standard argument).

The pairing $s(V_1,V_2)$ above should define a section $s$ of this bundle $\mu$. And it vanishes at a point $(V_1,V_2)$ if and only of $V_1\subset V_2$ so it should hold that $$Z(s) = Fl(k_1,k_2).$$
In that case, assuming the section to be transverse to the zero section, we have $$j^*\tau_{G_{k_1}(V)\times G_{k_2}(V)} \cong \tau_{Fl(k_1,k_2)}\oplus j^*\mu,\quad j:Fl(k_1,k_2)\hookrightarrow G_{k_1}(V)\times G_{k_2}(V),$$
so $\mu$ should indeed be a normal bundle.

I guess that I could replace this "annihilator bundle" $\gamma^{k_2}(V)^\circ$ by the dual of the quotient bundle $Q^{k_2}(V)^*$ of $\gamma^{k_2}(V)$ since they should be isomorphic.

My questions:

1. Is this construction valid or does it have some flaws?
2. This construction appears to be very standard knowledge, but I could not find similar arguments somewhere. Does anyone have any references? There should be a standard way to construct a normal bundle of flag varieties...

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "Is this construction valid or does it have some flaws?
This construction appears to be very standard knowledge, but I could not find similar arguments somewhere. Does anyone have any references? There should be a standard way to construct a normal bundle of flag varieties..."

**Answer:** You should look up the definition of the normal bundle: If $i:X \rightarrow Y$ is a regular embedding (over $S$), there is a sequence

$$K \rightarrow i^*\Omega^1_{Y/S} \rightarrow \Omega^1_{X/S} \rightarrow \Omega^1_{X/Y} \rightarrow 0$$

And $K$ is a finite rank locally trivial sheaf with $N_X(Y):=\mathbb{V}(K^*)$ the associated vector bundle.

In your case it follows $Y:=G_1\times G_2$ is a product of grassmannians and if

$$0 \rightarrow S_1\rightarrow \pi_1^*V \rightarrow Q_1 \rightarrow 0$$ is the tautological sequence on $G_1$ it follows

$$\tau_{G_1} \cong Hom (S_1,Q_1) \cong S_1^* \otimes Q_1$$

and

$$\Omega^1_{G_1/k} \cong S_1 \otimes Q_1^*.$$

It follows

$$\Omega^1_{G_1 \times G_2/k} \cong p_1^*\Omega^1_{G_1/k}\oplus p_2^*\Omega^1_{G_2/k}.$$

It follows

$$CF.\text{  }i^*\Omega_{Y/k}\cong q_1^*\Omega^1_{G_1/k} \oplus q_2^*\Omega^1_{G_2/k}$$

is an isomorphism where

$$q_i: F \rightarrow G_i$$

is the canonical "projection map" and $F:=F(k_1,k_2)$ is the flag variety. You get a sequence

$$ K \rightarrow q_1^*\Omega^1_{G_1/k}\oplus q_2^*\Omega^1_{G_2/k} \rightarrow \Omega^1_{F/k}$$

and this defines the normal bundle $N_F(G_1\times G_2)$. You must compare this construction with your construction. There is for the flag bundle $F$ a tautological flag

$$T1.\text{   } F_1 \subseteq F_1 \subseteq \pi^*V$$

where $\pi: F \rightarrow Spec(k)$ is the projection map and $\pi^*V$ is the trivial bundle on $F$ of rank $dim_k(V)$. If $x:=[V_1 \subseteq V_2]\in F(k)$ is a $k$-rational point, it follows

$$F_1(x)=V_1 \subseteq F_2(x)=V_2 \subseteq V$$

when you pass to the fiber of $T1$ at $x$. This is similar to what happens to the grassmannian $G_1$: If $x:=[V_1]\in G_1(k)$ is a point corresponding to $W \subseteq V$ you get the exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow S_1(x)\cong V_1 \rightarrow  V \rightarrow V/V_1 \rightarrow 0$$

gives back the $k_1$-dimensional $k$-vector space $V_1 \subseteq V$.

The fiber of $\Omega^1_{G_1/k} \cong S_1\otimes Q_1^*$ at $x$ is the vector space

$$S_1\otimes Q_1^*(x) \cong V_1 \otimes (V/V_1)^*.$$

Hence the fiber of $i^*\Omega^1_{G_1 \times G_2/k}$ at the $k$-rational point $y:=[V_1 \subseteq V_2]$ is the vector space

$$ V_1\otimes(V/V_1)^* \oplus V_2\otimes(V/V_2)^*.$$

You must interpret this in terms of the map $i^*\Omega^1_{G_1 \times G_2/k} \rightarrow \Omega^1_{F/k}$ and identify the kernel $K$.

**Comment:** "I guess that I could replace this "annihilator bundle" γk2(V)∘ by the quotient bundle Qk2(V) of γk2(V) since they should be isomorphic."

**Response:** I have not seen the "annihilator bundle" mentioned. There is a canonical map

$$<,>: V_2 \times V^* \rightarrow k$$

defined by

$$<v,\phi>:=\phi(v)$$

inducing a map

$$ f: V_2 \otimes_k V^* \rightarrow k$$

by $f(v\otimes \phi):=\phi(v)$. This induce a map

$$f^*: V^* \rightarrow Hom_k(V_2,k)$$

and $V_2^{\bullet}:=ker(f^*)$. You should formulate this notion precisely in terms of bundles and the tautological sequences on the grassmannian variety and flag variety. In fact for the grassmannian $G(k_2,V)$ there is the "dual" tautological sequence

$$0 \rightarrow Q_2^* \rightarrow \pi_2^*V^* \rightarrow S_2^* \rightarrow 0$$

and it may be $(S_2)^{\bullet}\cong Q_2^*$ is the dual of the quotient bundle $Q_2$. You should try to use the bundle $Q_2^*$ instead of the "annihilator bundle". From my argument you see that $Q_i^*$ is involved in formula $CF$ when calculating the cotangent bundle of the grassmannian and the flag variety.

My calculation gives

$$j^*\tau_{G_1 \times G_2/k}=f_1^*(S_1^*\otimes Q_1) \oplus f_2^*(S_2^*\otimes Q_2)$$

and

$$ j^*\mu=q_1^*(S_1^*)\otimes q_2^*(Q_2)$$

where $q_i: F(k_1,k_2) \rightarrow G_i$ is the canonical map $q_i([V_1 \subseteq V_2]):=[V_i] \in G_i$.

**Note:** There is another map that may be interesting:

$$f: F(k_1,k_2) \rightarrow G(k_1,V)\times G(k_2-k_1,V/V_1)$$

defined by

$$f([V_1,V_2]:=([V_1],[V_2/V_1]).$$

If you construct $F:=F(k_1,k_2):=SL(V)/P$ where $P$ is the parabolic subgroup fixing the flag, it follows

$$dim_k(\Omega^1_{F/k}(e)) =dim_k(Lie(SL(V))/Lie(P))=k_1(n-k_1)+(k_2-k_1)(n-k_2)$$

In algebraic geometry a reference is

Grothendieck, Alexander; Dieudonné, Jean A.
Éléments de géométrie algébrique. I. (English) Zbl 0203.23301
Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften. 166. Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. IX, 466 p. (1971).

There is a book by Akhiezer

Akhiezer, Dmitri N.
Lie group actions in complex analysis. (English) Zbl 0845.22001
Aspects of Mathematics. E27. Braunschweig: Vieweg. vii, 201 p. (1995).

where flag varieties are studied from the point of view of complex analysis.

**The quotient-approach:** There is another construction of the flag variety and vector bundles using quotients and representations. If $0\neq V_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq V_d \subsetneq V$ is a flag in $V$, let $P \subseteq SL(V)$ be the parabolic subgroup fixing the flag and construct the "quotient" $SL(V)/P$. (In algebraic geometry this quotient construction is "complicated".) Given any left $P$-module $\rho:P\times W \rightarrow W$ you may construct the associated vector bundle $\pi:V(\rho) \rightarrow SL(V)/P$. If you do this with the $P$-module $T:=Lie(SL(V))/Lie(P)$ you arrive at the tangent bundle $T_{SL(V)/P)}$. If you do this with the dual $T^*$ you arrive at the cotangent bundle $\Omega^1_{SL(V)/P}$. I believe there are references in Akhiezer's book.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I have to put some work into this, because my AG knowledge is very poor. I am more familiar with vector bundles from them differential geometric viewpoint.
The term "annihilator bundle" is nothing that exists in the literature but I came up with the idea since it suits my needs. One could directly use the quotient bundle and define the section as you did with the map "f". The only thing that worries me, is that our results for the normal bundle differ. I have $Q_2^*$ instead of $Q_2$ in the definition of $j^*\mu$...

Comment: @Teddyboer - you should make explicit the map defining the locally trivial sheaf $K$ at the beginning of my post.

Comment: I would like to do so, but I really have poor knowledge in algebraic geometry. So by $\Omega_{Y/S}^1$ you mean the conormal bundle of $Y$ over $S$? So it's fibers are the $1$ - forms living on the tangent space at a given point $y\in Y$? (Considering $X$ and $Y$ as manifolds of course)

Comment: You write "maybe $(S_2)^\circ\cong Q_2^*$" and that was my idea exactly. The annihilator of a subspace $V_2\subset V$ is isomorphic to the orthogonal subspace $V_2^\perp$ (if an inner product is defined). And $V_2^\perp$ can be considered as the fiber of $Q_2$ at $V_2$.

Comment: @Teddyboer - for the grassmannian variety the tangent and (cotangent bundle) is defined using the tautological sequence. I believe a similar construction exists for the flag variety but do not have a precise reference. If you look in the litterature on a construction of the flag variety you should find a description of these bundles.

Comment: Thank you again for all your remarks and edits. This is very helpful! I will take a closer look at the references.